# AWS Glue - Can't select fields after unnest or relationalize

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-glue, unnest

In AWS S3 I have json docs that I read-in with AWS Glue's `create_dynamic_frame.from_options("s3" ...)` and the DynamicFrame.printSchema() shows me this, which matches the schema of the documents:

```
root
|-- updatedAt: string
|-- json: struct
|    |-- rowId: int
```

Then I `unnest()` or `relationalize()` (have tried both) the DynamicFrame to a new dyF and then `.printSchema()` shows me this, which seems correctly unnested:

```
root
|-- updatedAt: string
|-- json.rowId: int
```

The problem is that I can't seem to use the nested fields.
`dyF.select_fields(["updatedAt"])` will work and give me a dyF with the "updatedAt" field. 
But 
 `dyF.select_fields(["json.rowId"])` gives me an empty dyF.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use backticks around the column name.

Example: `` .select_fields(["journalId", "`json.rowId`"]) ``

Comment: Where is this thing documented @user12166 ? Spent more than 2 days trying to figure out what was going on. I was trying to join nested columns and was going to give up and raise premium AWS enterprise case for this.